# MiniProfiler can't display SqlTimings

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I am using MiniProfiler to Profile My MVC app and WCF services, this works like a charm with one caveat - when the profile information contains sql.

Symptoms:

1. The "query time (ms)" heading is missing from the popup
2. The "% in sql" is also missing from the bottom of the popup
3. If I click on the " sql" links it shows the grey overlay but no information and throws some jQuery error (it can't find the element).

After a little digging I discovered that this is all to do with **HasSqlTimings** in the json response there is an inconsistency between HasSqlTimings (false) at the root of the json response and the information that is in Root / Children hierarchy (true).

```
[OnDeserialized]
void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
{
    HasSqlTimings = GetTimingHierarchy().Any(t => t.HasSqlTimings);
    HasDuplicateSqlTimings = GetTimingHierarchy().Any(t => t.HasDuplicateSqlTimings);

    if (_root != null)
    {
        _root.RebuildParentTimings();
    }
}
```

I took a look at the source and it looks like it should work just fine but no deal!  Does anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when implementing this. The issue occurs when the UI layer doesn't make any sql calls but then the WCF data comes back with sql calls. The root timing doesn't know there are sql timings below in the hierarchy.

I added one line so that when adding "remote" timings we set the "hasSqlTimings" field so that the UI knows how to render the box properly.  Here is the code I modified in MvcMiniProfiler\MiniProfiler.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds <paramref name="externalProfiler"/>'s <see cref="Timing"/> hierarchy to this profiler's current Timing step,
/// allowing other threads, remote calls, etc. to be profiled and joined into this profiling session.
/// </summary>
public static void AddProfilerResults(this MiniProfiler profiler, MiniProfiler externalProfiler)
{
   if (profiler == null || externalProfiler == null) return;
   profiler.Head.AddChild(externalProfiler.Root);
   profiler.HasSqlTimings = profiler.GetTimingHierarchy().Any(t => t.HasSqlTimings);
}
```

Comment: I've submitted a bug for this: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=124&thanks=124&ts=1321969953